# Filter Logic - Parentheses Error

Tags: formula

I receive the following error when trying to create filter logic: "To use successive AND-OR expressions, add parentheses".

~~EDIT~~

To shorten this using less numbers, here is another version of my issue:

- 1 AND (3 OR ((4 AND 5) OR (6 AND 7) AND 8))

**Here is a longer version that DOES work**... I just want to reduce the number of times I display "8" in the logic, which is why I'm trying to use 8 only once on the outside of the logic versus repeating it:

- 1 AND (3 OR (4 AND 5 AND 8) OR (6 AND 7 AND 8))

Comment: Both filter logic are completely valid, but I think the question is why they didn't work. Please [edit] your question and add some context of what is 1, 2, and so on. Where is this used?

Comment: @HengkyIlawan No, they are both invalid.

Answer (score 2):

Within each parentheses group, there must be ONLY *and* or *or* operators.

See:

```
((...) OR (...) AND ...)
```

As you can see, you have an OR and AND in the same group.

Without knowing your logic, it's hard to tell if this is what you meant, but a valid filter would be:

```
1 AND 2 AND (3 OR (4 AND 5) OR (6 AND 7 AND 8)) AND 9 AND 10
```

---

Edit: Based on your edit:

```
1 AND (3 OR (8 AND ((4 AND 5) OR (6 AND 7))))
```

Every time you transition between OR and AND, you have to have another group of parentheses. I'm pretty sure this is as short as you can make this logic.

Comment: I've made an edit to my question using a version that does work. Can you give it a look, please?

Comment: @dms04d Edited. Note that you really only saved two characters, so not entirely sure that was worth it, but maybe you'll find a use for it.

Comment: @sfdcfox Is there any POC to validate the Filter logic?

Comment: @SFDC wouldn't be too hard to write one. I'll post it when it's ready.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank You that would be helpful :)

Comment: @SFDC I wouldn't call this one "production ready", but I wrote a small page that performs basic sanity checks for filters. This one should closely match what Salesforce allows, or at least provide a sanity check to make sure you haven't done something wrong. [Demo](https://studio.webcomponents.dev/edit/Biu9u65B8uaHpxwigotm/src/app.js?p=stories).